# Get filtered row names and save it in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
       Area         2016-09-02  2016-09-03  2016-09-04  2016-09-05  
     39.TFO 1-14     6588.67     6604.03     6567.42     6421.12   
    40.TFO 15-28     6843.58     6929.41     6922.24     6801.98   
    41.TFO 29-42     3546.59     3634.46     3770.85     3813.15   
    42.TFO 43-52     3816.58     3834.43     3830.02     3822.59
```

I want to save Area Values in a list like

[TFO 1-14, TFO 15-28, TFO 29-42, TFO 43-52]

I have tried this code but i am getting the wrong output.

df['Area'].str.extract('TFO (.*)'))

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [indexing-with-str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
print (df['Area'].str.split('.').str[1].tolist())
['TFO 1-14', 'TFO 15-28', 'TFO 29-42', 'TFO 43-52']
```

Another solution with [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print (df['Area'].str.extract('(TFO .*)', expand=False).tolist())
['TFO 1-14', 'TFO 15-28', 'TFO 29-42', 'TFO 43-52']
```